# Selenium Webdriver Python side-by-side

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to use both the selenium functionality and the webdriver functionality in the same program? I am trying to take a screenshot and selenium is crashing at that command ".capture_entire_page_screenshot(...)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try mixing SeleniumRC (the version 1 API) with WebDriver (version 2 API). That would be twice the pain and none of the pleasure.

Using webdriver, have you tried

```
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    # driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/google.png')
    driver.save_screenshot('/tmp/google.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what error you are seeing? Maybe there is something wrong with your code. This works perfectly for me in Selenium 1:

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class IIIAppforloop(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.yahoo.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_i_i_i_appforloop(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load(60000)
        sel.capture_entire_page_screenshot(r"C:\picture.png", " ")


    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```